# Multilingual App for the Mac App Store - where to set languages displayed in Mac App Store?

Tags: xcode, macos, multilingual, mac-app-store

I have a Mac Osx App to submit to the Mac App Store - it supports 8 languages.

Its written mostly in pure C++, i use my own localization handling, so
i DON'T use any localization strings provided by XCode.

Question: Where can i set these languages, so it gets displayed in the Mac App Store ?

- Somewhere in xcode (in some .plist ?)
- Somewhere in iTunes connect ?

Thanks for you help,
Roman

Comment: follow this link from apple:https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your AppName-Info.plist file, add the key `CFBundleLocalizations` with an array of locale strings for your supported languages.

The full Info.plist documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html